# How to send two parameters to Onchange function in select

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code

```
        <option value="">Select State</option>
                        <?php
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
         {
          echo "<option value=".$row['state_id'].">".$row['state']."     </option>";
         }
         ?>
                        </select>
                        </label>




                        <label style="margin-left:20px; width:200px; float:left; padding-top:6px;">

                        <select name="city" id="city" onChange="getArea('indexcontroller/indexmodules/findarea.php?city='+this.value)" style="width:220px;margin-left:3px;height:39px;margin-top:6px;">
                        <option value="">Select City/Town</option>
                        </select>
```

How can i send value selected in state to getArea()

Comment: We don't know what you want to do. Can you expatiate on your question. 
I think it'll be nicer if you post the function `getArea()`. Even so, you can send the two parameters in that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<select name="city" id="city" onChange="getArea('indexcontroller/indexmodules/findarea.php?city='+$('#StatedropDownId').val();)" style="width:220px;margin-left:3px;height:39px;margin-top:6px;">
```

Comment: How do you know OP is using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I would select the element by id and get its value

```
<select id="stateSelect">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    ...
</select>

<select id="citySelect" onchange="getArea('indexcontroller/indexmodules/findarea.php?state=' + document.getElementById('stateSelect').value + '&city='+this.value)">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    ...
</select>
```